# Calibre install hosed my desktop

Tags: desktop-environments, calibre

So I installed *Calibre* -- the epub reader -- on my Xenial drive and noticed
right away that the icons on my top-panel & my desktop were suddenly all-white with a red "X" on them.

I re-booted, and the login screen was black (background image totally not 
there), but the username & password boxes still appeared, so at least I could
log in.

The second I was logged in, although I could see that my startup programs had loaded, instantly the entire screen on both my monitors did this whole BLINK-BLINK-BLINK-BLINK thing and just kept up like that. So I can't use my
16.04 system and am posting this from my 14.04 drive.

I installed Calibre according to the instructions on its download page [here](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux). The 
command used was this:

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py | sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
```

I later removed Calibre with the recommended "sudo calibre-uninstall" but of
course the desktop was, and is, still broken.

On the download page, below the install command, it says:

"You must have xdg-utils, wget and python ≥ 2.6 installed on your system before running the installer."

Since I have python 3.5 installed (and xdg-utls and wget), I didn't anticipate a problem.

Can anyone suggest what steps I might take to recover a functioning desktop in this situation?

Minor update: What's going on is strobe-light style flickering, but I've discovered I can actually enter commands between the flickers.  Also, there are held broken packages, and I have to figure out how to deal with those. Re-installation of my Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 just isn't an option, except as an absolute final completely last-ditch effort.

Comment: How did you know you didn't have Python 2? Ubuntu 16.04 by default comes with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: That's what I thought, and perhaps I do have it, but mounting my 16.04 drive from 14.04, and doing a search in 16.04's Caja (UbuntuMate's Nautilus-equivalent) on "python" shows a whole lot, but no "python-2x" anything.

Comment: Can you do `readlink -e $(which python python2 python3)` and let me know what it says?

Comment: I edited the post slightly.  I don't have access to a commandline on 16.04, but on 14.04: 

`--> readlink -e $(which python python2 python3) 

/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3.4`

Comment: Why not install calibre using the system package? (I know it's a bit outdated...)

Comment: @Bharadwaj My goal at this point is not to install Calibre -- forget Calibre -- I want to get my desktop back.  I get nothing but blinking if I try to log into my Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 install.  This happened as a result of my installation of Calibre.

Comment: @watchpocket Then try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop`

Comment: @edwinksl That python 2.7.6 is on my 14.04 drive.  I'm not sure I have a python 2 on my 16.04 drive (that's where the desktop is corrupted), as a search shows a lot of python35 but no python2.  I never un-installed it, but it seems odd that it doesn't show in search.

Comment: @watchpocket Your Ubuntu 16.04 probably wouldn't be very functional if Python 2 were missing. In any case, reinstall your desktop environment as Bharadwaj Raju suggested, since that is more important for now.

Comment: How would I do that from my 14.04 terminal? I can do 'sudo ls -la /media/rj/UbuntuMATE-16.04' and get the 16.04 root file list, but wouldn't I have to run that command from within 16.04?

Comment: @watchpocket Boot into the (blank, I know) 16.04 install, then press `Ctrl-Alt-F2` to get to a terminal (the Linux virtual-terminal). Login and do the `apt` thing from there.

Comment: Strangely, `Ctrl-Alt-F2` didn't bring up a prompt (nor did `Ctrl-Alt-F-anything`), so I logged into Xenial's failsafe mode & got the large-print root shell-promt. 

I entered `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop`, which returned a message indicating two unmet dependencies for ubuntu-mate-desktop: `apturl` ("but it is not installable"), and `ubuntu-mate-core` ("but it is not going to be installed").  Also "E: Unable to correct problems. You have broken packages.")

Comment: At this point, I think only a reinstall would help

Comment: But try `apt install --reinstall -f ubuntu-mate-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I had the same problem this evening, and was able to resolve it by installing *all* of the dependencies of ubuntu-desktop.

I got the list with apt-cache depends, grepped for depends, cleaned it up with sed and fed it into xargs apt-get --reinstall install -y.

Apparently starting the newer calibre versions does something funny to permissions somewhere or something like that.

Comment: `apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop | grep Depends | sed 's/  Depends: //' | xargs apt-get --reinstall install -y`